# place for storing custom IPrincipal

Tags: asp.net

I'm using my custom IPrincipal, because I need some additional fields, like id and password (logging to outer wcf service). I'm setting the principal in the Application_PostAuthenticateRequest event, but it must be done on every request. I want to cache it in some place, but what is the best solution for it? Session is unavailale. I have there a password, so I don't want to use the FormsAuthenticationTicket even if it is encrypted. HttpContext.Current.Items stores values only for one request. The objects Application and Cache are available for each users. What are other possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

The best option to store a possibly unlimited amount of custom information would be a cookie. Remember however, that Forms cookies are limited in size and if you exceed the size, the infrastructure just doesn't work.

One of possible approaches would be to switch to federated cookies issued by the `SessionAuthenticationModule`. I've blogged on how to seamlessly switch to this module if you use forms authentication:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2012/09/forms-authentication-revisited.html

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2012/09/sessionauthenticationmodule-and-dynamic.html